# Python Quandl installed but not importing

Tags: python, quandl

I am using python 2.7 and I have installed quandl, and it shows up on my pip list, however, when I try and import it, it pops up this error:

"ImportError: No module named quandl"

Here is what I have so far in my .py file:

```
import pandas
import quandl
```

Here is a photo of quandl on my pip list, so it is installed. I have also tried Quandl and quandl as the name, but neither of them works. I can't figure out what else could be wrong with this.

[image]

Comment: Did you use virtual environments?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is using Anaconda for this, I just discovered that Quandl has a module in the `conda` package manager.

Try `conda install quandl` in the terminal, then `import quandl` on Python 3. The "Q" seems to be capitalized on Python 2.7 installs.